# изменить цвет (когда нажата) TabItem в TabControl

Tags: c++, c++builder, text, color, radstudio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как полоска внизу выбраного Item и текст задать другого цвета??

Comment: OnChangiпg и OnChange события при переключении, в них и меняйте то, что вам нужно

Comment: Цвет там я поменяю. А полоску как?  Где то задан же этот стандартный цвет, и думаю его можно поменять

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636713/change-the-color-of-the-selected-tabitem-footer Вот нашел, мб кому понадобится!

Comment: можете сами оформить ответ на свой вопрос, указав ссылку и описав свои действия и пометить его ка правильный ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ:

1) нужно в программе BitmapStyleDesigner (\папка с RadStudio\xx.x\bin\BitmapStyleDesigner) создать стиль.

2)сохранить его в формате Fmx(.style).

3)Добавить на форму визуальный компонент StyleBook.

4)Кликнув по нему дважды, добавить туда созданый стиль.

5)Задать основной Form свойство StyleBook, в котором выбрать тот StyleBook который вы добавили.